# Ormlite: Why does where.eq(columnname, value) give wrong results?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

So I am using ormlite to handle my sqlite database in android. Unfortunately, I am getting unexpected results using dao.queryBuilder().where().eq().queryFirst().
Here is my function :

```
public static Person getByEmail(Dao<Person, ?> dao, String email) {
    try {
        Log.e("queriedEmail", email);
        return dao.queryBuilder().where()
                .eq(Person.EMAIL_FIELD, email)
                .queryForFirst();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I have actually checked the email being passed and the person object I get. Both have completely different emails.

The above function is called by

```
public static Person getByEmail(MyApp app, String email) {
    try {
        return getByEmail(app.getDatabaseHelper().getDao(
                Person.class), email);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

It'd be awesome if someone could point out where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got a solution. queryBuilder is actually giving wrong results so I used ormlite [queryRaw](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Raw-Queries) instead of queryBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

> So I am using ormlite to handle my sqlite database in android. Unfortunately, I am getting unexpected results using dao.queryBuilder().where().eq().queryFirst().

You seem to be implying that `QueryBuilder` is not working because of some sort of bug.  It's not impossible but it is much more likely that you are using in incorrectly.  I would use a debugger to figure out what is going on.  To see what sort of query is being generated, you can also turn on [ORMLite's Android logs](http://ormlite.com/docs/android-logging).

Some things to look into:

- Make sure that your `Person.EMAIL_FIELD` is what you expect.
- Looks like you are printing `email` so that field should be ok but a `null` value might also be the problem.
- Etc.

Best of luck debugging the bug.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your answer, I wanted to know is there a way to see the actual arguments passed to queries? I read the referenced docs but couldn't find my answer. Thanks!

Comment: If you turn on trace logging, you should see the args as well.